# Cartesian square in the category of Algebraic stacks

Tags: ag.algebraic-geometry, dg.differential-geometry, moduli-spaces, algebraic-stacks

Suppose we have a commutative diagram of Artin stacks

$ \newcommand{\ra}[1]{\kern-1.5ex\xrightarrow{\ \ #1\ \ }\phantom{}\kern-1.5ex} \newcommand{\ras}[1]{\kern-1.5ex\xrightarrow{\ \ \smash{#1}\ \ }\phantom{}\kern-1.5ex} \newcommand{\da}[1]{\bigg\downarrow\raise.5ex\rlap{\scriptstyle#1}}$

$$ \begin{array}{c} A & \ra{} & B  \\  \da{} & & \da{} & \\ C & \ra{} & D  \end{array} $$

Suppose I want to prove that such a given commutative square is a fibre product diagram i.e., a cartesian square. Is it enough to show that the following square is cartesian?

$$ \begin{array}{c} ho(A(\mathbb C)) & \ra{} & ho(B(\mathbb C))  \\  \da{} & & \da{} & \\ ho(C(\mathbb C)) & \ra{} & ho(D(\mathbb C))  \end{array} $$

Here $A(\mathbb C)$ denotes the groupoid of $\mathbb C$ valued points of $A$ and ho denotes the underlying set of isomorphism classes.

After reading Sasha's counterexample, I should mention that all 4 stacks in my case are reduced local complete intersections.

Comment: Definitely no, even for schemes. For instance, take $B$, $C$, and $D$ to be $\mathrm{Spec}(\mathbb{C})$ and take $A$ to be $\mathrm{Spec}(\mathbb{C}[t]/t^2)$.

Comment: @Sasha In my case all 4 Stacks are reduced and local complete intersections

Comment: OK, take $B = C = D$ to be a plane nodal cubic curve and let $A$ be its normalization.

Comment: Sorry, I meant cuspidal cubic curve.

Comment: Even putting aside schemey issues mentioned above, this seems to fail in almost all cases just for groupoids in sets. E.g. what if all four stacks are classifying stacks of finite groups?